# Puzzle — 20 People to consume 20 units of food under constraints

Tags: functional-style, diophantine-equations, puzzle

I am learning Mathematica because I love it. I also love solving puzzles so I think it would be a nice way to learn Mathematica through puzzles. This is first puzzle in series I intend to solve.

So here is the problem.

- People = 20
- Food = 20
- Restrictions;

  - A man eats 2 units
  - A woman consumes 1.5 units
  - A baby can take only .5 units of food
  - Combined number of men women and babies must equal 20
  - All units of food must be consumed.

There are four possible solutions, I would like to learn

1. shortest syntax to get a random solution
2. syntax/program which gives all possible solution

Comment: @m_goldberg I disagree with change of tag as it is an iteration problem. i.e. it has less number of equations to solve than the variables, so no matrix solution is possible for them. Only way to solve such problem is through iteration. So iteration tag was best suited here.

Comment: No iteration is needed to solve this problem in Mathematica.

Comment: Alright then, if you think you can do that then do it on paper.

You will find getting solutions to questions which have less number of equations than variables (which make the equations) is not easy. Because you will have to hit and try to get correct answer

Anyway, if you REALLY KNOW that there is a way to solve such kind of puzzles/questions then do tell me I am always eager to learn.

Comment: You already got an answer from mikado that doesn't use iteration.

Comment: @m_goldberg if that was not iteration then I don't know what is.

Comment: @Jawad_Mansoor That was, in fact, *not* an iterative procedure as I understand it. An iteration process generates [a sequence of improving approximate solutions for a problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method). That is not what happens in the solutions proposed below. Those are all *direct* methods.

Comment: @MarcoB thank you for replying. Okay, but I thought that was happening in the answers. I mean, it will evaluate one answer if it is in correct then it will go to find another answer until it finds the correct answer.

So, what is direct method?

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you for improving question

Comment: Both of the replying members, Goldberg and Macro, can you put some links here which can differentiate between iterative and direct questions and answers so that my understanding of them becomes better. Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We can do this *more efficiently* using [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html):

```
Counts /@ IntegerPartitions[20, {20}, {1, 3, 4}/2]
```

> ```
> {
>  <|2 -> 6, 3/2 -> 1, 1/2 -> 13|>,
>  <|2 -> 4, 3/2 -> 4, 1/2 -> 12|>,
>  <|2 -> 2, 3/2 -> 7, 1/2 -> 11|>,
>  <|3/2 -> 10, 1/2 -> 10|>
> }
> ```

Also as requested code for only one solution:

```
Counts /@ IntegerPartitions[20, {20}, {1, 3, 4}/2, 1]
```

> ```
> {<|2 -> 6, 3/2 -> 1, 1/2 -> 13|>}
> ```

This does not generate all and then throw some away; it only generates the one requested.

As a rule when working any problem similar to this I try to apply `IntegerPartitions` as when it fits it is usually much faster than `Solve`, `Reduce`, etc.  Some examples:

- [How do I generate a set of n-tuples containing integral solutions to a linear equation provided certain constraints?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22397/121#22400)
- [How to merge permutations obtained from Solve on multiple variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73120/121#73132)
- [Diophantine and odd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79587/121)

Comment: Nice. I didn't know we could use rationals in `IntegerPartitions`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you for introducing me to this option of IntegerPartitions. Useful for 'Nickel and Dime' problems...:)

Comment: @mr.wizard thank you. I never imagined a community so prolific with genius minds and yet to humble and generous. Thank you all, everybody for participating.

I know I need to learn a lot and this is my starting point and I see it is good for many other people as well they are learning too.

Comment: @mr.wizard how do you make hyper links appear like that? They are neat and short. I mean I don't see a full length link like 

[Link] http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22397/how-do-i-generate-a-set-of-n-tuples-containing-integral-solutions-to-a-linear-eq#22400 [/Link] 

Instead of just a few words as you mentioned **integerpartitions** (off site link) and three on site links.

Comment: @Jawad For the first kind I am using the **Ref** button added by halirutan's wonderful [toolbar extension](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1044/121).  The three links at the bottom are auto-formatted by the site software; simply include a bare URL like `http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79587/` and it appears as a link with a proper title.  Start a line with `- ` to create a "bullet point" as I used for those last three links.

Answer (score 21):

Just write the problem literally and use `Reduce`

```
Reduce[
 m >= 0 && w >= 0 && b >= 0 && {m, w, b} ∈ Integers && 
  2 m + 3/2 w + 1/2 b == 20 && m + w + b == 20, {m, w, b}]

(* (m == 0 && w == 10 && b == 10) || (m == 2 && w == 7 && b == 11) || 
   (m == 4 && w == 4 && b == 12)  || (m == 6 && w == 1 && b == 13) *)
```

Comment: man that was fast, and thank you. :) Really appreciate that.

Comment: I found these also work

'Reduce[2 m + 3/2 w + 1/2 b == 20 && {m, w, b} \[Element] 
   Integers && {m, w, b} >= 0 && m + w + b == 20]'

And

'Reduce[2 m + 3/2 + 1/2 b == 20 && 
  w + m + b == 20 && {m, w, b} >= 0, {m, w, b}, Integers]'

But since they are based on your code so kudos to you my friend. Also, I just copied the e 'MEMBER' I don't know how to write it. How to write e?

Comment: I don't know how to format code in code format, as you did. Please tell me how to format that also. Thank you

Comment: @Jawad to format code use backward apostrophes, the top left key of my keyboard, with the tilde (~).

Comment: `Reduce[2 m + 3/2 w + 1/2 b == 20 && {m, w, b} [Element] Integers && {m, w, b} >= 0 && m + w + b == 20]`


`Reduce[2 m + 3/2 + 1/2 b == 20 && w + m + b == 20 && {m, w, b} >= 0, {m, w, b}, Integers]`

Thank @NicholasG man

Answer (score 18):

Another solution:

```
Select[FrobeniusSolve[{20, 15, 5}, 200], Total[#] == 20 &]
```

> `{{0, 10, 10}, {2, 7, 11}, {4, 4, 12}, {6, 1, 13}}`

The first element in each list is the number of men, the second element is the number of women, and the third element is the number of babies.

Comment: I did not understand that solution at all. However it is correct. But how does it work, please explain.

Comment: @Jawad_Mansoor You have to read the documentation for `FrobeniusSolve` as that is the core of the solution. The `Select` comes from the fact that `FrobeniusSolve` returns all possible combinations of any number of men, women, and children. `Select` picks out just those solutions where the total number of people is 20.

Answer (score 10):

YAW: Yet Another Way.

FindInstance seems created for such tasks:

Let m = number of men, w = number of women, b = number of babies.

```
FindInstance[{2 m + (3/2) w + (1/2) b == 20, m + w + b == 20, m >= 0, w >= 0, b >= 0}, {m, w, b}, Integers, 10]

(*{{m -> 0, w -> 10, b -> 10}, {m -> 2, w -> 7, b -> 11}, {m -> 4,  w -> 4, b -> 12}, {m -> 6, w -> 1, b -> 13}}*)
```

Comment: Okay, it seams to be working, but where does the 10 in the end come from? I appreciate help. Thank you

Comment: That tells FindInstance to look for 10 solutions, else it will only look for 1 by default. Remember, the number of solutions was a given. I wanted to be sure that there were no others.

Answer (score 8):

Not all solutions, but the one that minimizes the number of babies to feed

```
LinearProgramming[{0, 0, 1}, {{2, 1.5, .5}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{20, 0}, {20, 0}}, 0, Integers]
```

Comment: thank you that was really nice. by the way do you hate babies?

Comment: @Jawad_Mansoor Terrified